# matlab symbolic solve system of linear equations in terms of specific variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I would like to solve the following system of equation in terms of g3
[image]

The following code returns one possible solution.

```
syms g0 g1 g2 g3 x mu3 mu4 mu5 mu6 gamma
A = [1, 0, 1, mu3; 0, 1, mu3, mu4; 1, mu3, mu4, mu5];
B = [0; 0; gamma];
X = linsolve(A,B);
```

But I would like to have a solution for g0, g1 and g2 in terms of g3.

How can I specify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your problem into the following equivalent formulation under the form of a square system :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&\mu_3\\1&\mu_3&\mu_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}g_0\\g_1\\g_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\mu_3g_3\\-\mu_4g_3\\\gamma-\mu_5g_3\\\end{pmatrix}$$

giving the following Matlab formulation:

> ```
> syms g0 g1 g2 g3 x mu3 mu4 mu5 mu6 gamma
> A = [1, 0, 1; 0, 1, mu3; 1, mu3, mu4];
> B = [ -mu3*g3; -mu4*g3; gamma-mu5*g3];
> X = linsolve(A,B)
> ```

giving:

> ```
> g0 = (- g3*mu3^3 + 2*g3*mu4*mu3 + gamma - g3*mu5)/D
> g1 = (gamma*mu3 - g3*mu4 + g3*mu3^2 + g3*mu4^2 - g3*mu3*mu5)/D
> g2 = -(gamma + g3*mu3 - g3*mu5 + g3*mu3*mu4)/D
> with D:=(mu3^2 - mu4 + 1)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Append a fourth row to $A$, with values $(0,0,0,1)$.

Also add a fourth element to $B$, with value the desired $g_3$.

Then when you solve 
$$
Ax = B
$$
the solution will give you $g_0, g_1, g_2$ read off from the first three elements of $x$, and you will notice that in the solution, the last element of $x$ is $g_3$.

Why does that work?  Because the fourth equation you have added is $x_3=g_3$.

Answer (score 1):

It also works if `solve` instead of `linsolve` is employed

```
syms g0 g1 g2 g3 x mu3 mu4 mu5 mu6 gamma

eqn1 = g0 + g2 + g3*mu3 == 0;
eqn2 = g1 + g2*mu3 + g3*mu4 ==0;
eqn3 = g0 + g1*mu3 + g2*mu4 + g3*mu5 == gamma;

g = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3], [g0, g1, g2]);
```

Comment: Interesting, but one can think "linsolve" is more appropriate than "solve" for linear systems  because there exists very specific methods for linear cases that should be far more efficient than for general equations.